# Exception Handling in REST

Tags: rest, exception, wcf

I have created a REST service using WCF for communicating with BLL/DAL from UI. Now, I would like to implement Exception Handling through some globalize way in REST. I am using HTTPClient to communicate with REST from client. The following are the ways, I have implemented exception handling:

Approach 1:

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
success = false;
```

Approach 2:

```
throw new WebProtocolException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message, null);
```

but somehow I am not able to catch them in the client side. Kindly suggest some pointers in order to handle exceptions raised by service globally.

---

I am throwing WebProtocolException (Approach 2) along with error code and error message from the service to UI in order to notify users about the exception. I am able to receive the error code in UI side but not getting error message or detail.

Then I created another service (having .svc extension) and added following line to the service's markup: "Factory='Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2Factory'". Now, I am able to receive the error message along with error code on client side (UI).

Can anybody let me know how to use the WebServiceHost2Factory method in my existing service which is a class file instead of .svc file?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but WebServiceHost2Factory is in REST Starter Kit which is deprecated and the license effectively prevents use of it now that .Net 4 is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient does not throw exceptions when a response comes back that is not "successful".  If you really want exceptions to be thrown on the client side, then call

```
response.EnsureResponseIsSuccessful();
```

Otherwise, just check the status code on the client and decide what to do based on that value.

You cannot throw exceptions on the server and expect the exceptions to be propagated to the client.  HTTP does not have any notion of exception.

Comment: I am already calling "response.EnsureResponseIsSuccessful" method. I am able to verify the Status Code but not able to check the Status Description which I have passed from the Service to the client. Can you please suggest how should I pass the detailed error message to the clients in order to notify them the exact error occurred in the service.

Comment: @Anil C  Ahh, I believe it is a bug in the HTTP stack implementation.  It's fixed in the next gen HttpClient at http://wcf.codeplex.com and they got the name right too now "ReasonPhrase".

Comment: @Anil C  Instead of using the Status Description, why not just use the response body to explain the problem.  That's what RFC2616 recommends you do.

Comment: I have modified my question. Kindly suggest something else.